# In Cloud Spanner, Is RFC 3339 the only format for TIMESTAMP type?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

In Cloud Spanner, Is RFC 3339 the only format for TIMESTAMP type? Seems to be the case from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

The client-side format used for reading/writing TIMESTAMP values depends on what language you are using.

The [GoogleSQL docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#canonical_format_for_timestamp_literals) specify the canonical formats:

- [SQL Timestamp literals](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#timestamp_literals) have a format which is close to RFC-3339, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.FZ' but allow either 'T' or space to separate date/time, optional leading zeros, and optional time zone suffix. However there are many SQL functions for converting timestamps to/from other representations, such as Unix timestamps in millis
- For REST and RPC APIs (your first link is to the REST API), RFC-3339 is used with required time zone suffix.
- For client libraries, the [client library documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries) for the language specifies the format required/returned by the API (eg for Java: the [Timestamp class](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-core/latest/com.google.cloud.Timestamp))